# Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dialog has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, progressdialog

I just started learning Kotlin. I am using a custom ProgressDialog. Everytime I press back from the MainActivity, the app crashes with the following error:

```
  Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dialog has not been initialized
    at com.devApps.blog.CustomProgressDialog.getDialog(CustomProgressDialog.kt:17)
```

Here is my CustomProgressDialog :

```
  private val progressDialognew = CustomProgressDialog()
  lateinit var dialog: CustomDialog

fun show(context: Context): Dialog {
    return show(context, null)
}

fun show(context: Context, title: CharSequence?): Dialog {
    val inflater = (context as Activity).layoutInflater
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog_view, null)
    if (title != null) {
        view.cp_title.text = title
    }
    dialog = CustomDialog(context)
    dialog.setContentView(view)
    dialog.show()
    return dialog
}
```

And this is my MainActivity code :

```
 private val progressDialognew = CustomProgressDialog()
 progressDialognew.show(this, "Optimizing Image...")
 {
    my tasks here
 }

  override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    progressDialognew.dialog.dismiss()
}
```

UPDATE : I did as suggested now I am getting the same Error in the show() at the return dialog line. How to fix that ?

```
 lateinit var dialog: CustomDialog


fun show(context: Context): Dialog {
    return show(context, null)
}

fun show(context: Context, title: CharSequence?): Dialog {
    if (::dialog.isInitialized) {
        val inflater = (context as Activity).layoutInflater
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog_view, null)
        if (title != null) {
            view.cp_title.text = title
        }

        dialog = CustomDialog(context)
        dialog.setContentView(view)
        dialog.show()
       
    }
    return dialog
}

   
}

fun hideProgress() {

    if (::dialog.isInitialized) {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

    }
```

Complete StackTrace :

```
 kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dialog has not been initialized
    at com.devApps.blog.CustomProgressDialog.show(CustomProgressDialog.kt:50)
    at com.devApps.blog.PostActivity.upload(PostActivity.kt:328)
    at com.devApps.blog.PostActivity.post(PostActivity.kt:320)
    at com.devApps.blog.PostActivity.access$post(PostActivity.kt:54)
    at com.devApps.blog.PostActivity$onCreate$5$2.onClick(PostActivity.kt:198)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you close the activity without ever showing the dialog, this exception will happen. Because the `dialog` property in your `CustomProgressDialog` gets initialized only in `show()` method.

And `onDestroy()` method of the activity calls `dismiss()` on the `dialog` property that might not be initialized.

You can check if it's initialized first before dismissing it, consider adding this method inside `CustomProgressDialog`:

```
fun dismissDialog() {
    if (::dialog.isInitialized) {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```

And call it from the activity:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    progressDialognew.dismissDialog()
}
```

Comment: thanks Sir, youre a life saver, But I am again getting same error at another Line, Please check the Updated Question above. :)

Comment: please post the complete stacktrace for the error, and how you're calling the show() method

Comment: inside the `show()` method you don't need to check if the dialog is initialilzed, revert it back and i believe it'll work

Comment: posted sir, please check above

Comment: It worked, Thanks Sir, just have to remove the Line from show(). :)